# check sqlite android database is open or close

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I create a class and extended from `SQLiteOpenHelper` for copy and using sqlite database in my Android app. This class contain two methods :

```
public void OpenDatabase();
```

and

```
public void CloseDatabase();
```

for open and close database.
in the other activity and classes how can i check my database now is open or close?

Comment: your mantra should be `open it, use it. close it`. NEVER leave it open!

Comment: @Rotwang - if you have functions that do seperate bits of work with the db being called in sequence it makese sense to leave it open. For example, if you have functions that update a single column and you need to update three columns. can be taxing to open and close a dabase 3 times in a row

Comment: @pamblam Why can't you do an UPDATE that updates 3 columns at once? I can. For operations that involve a batch of commands there are **transactions**. Again: `open it, use it, close it`. It's a mantra. I write programs since 32 years. And this mantra **never failed** me.

Comment: sure it will work, i'm just saying, if you know you're doing several things with the database and you have fuctions to do these things, it's not always going to be efficient..

Comment: @Pamblam **Transactions** are very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check if the database is already in use by calling `isDbLockedByCurrentThread` or `isDbLockedByOtherThreads` on the single SQLiteDatabase object every time before you use it. this will prevent multiple manipulations to the database and save your application from a potential crash

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag in your class to keep track..

```
class poop extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private boolean isDBOpenf = false;
    public void OpenDatabase(){
        // open database
        isDBOpenf = true;
    }
    public void CloseDatabase(){
        // close database
        isDBOpenf = false;
    }
    public boolean isDBOpen(){ return isDBOpenf; }
}
```